# Substitute DataFrame column values for a friendly name

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

Is it possible to apply a mask to a dataframe column in the moment of it's creation?

I have the following scenario:

```
Name   Age   Event
Ian    23    1
Ana    26    2
Mark   54    2
John   15    3
```

Each event value corresponds to a friendly name which is stored in a dict

```
event_types = {
  1: 'Event 1',
  2: 'Event 2',
  3: 'Event 3'
}
```

And I want to replace this the event values from the dataframe to its corresponding value from the dict

What I have already tried this along with other variants, unsuccessfully

```
  for event_type in event_types:
        data.filter(['event_type']).mask(data == event_type, other=event_types[event_type])
```

I achieved the expected result using `.loc` and `lambda` but had performance issues, because the DataFrame contains millions of records

Any ideas how can I change the event column values for it's friendly name?

Comment: did you try map/replace? `df['Event']=df['Event'].map(event_types).fillna(df['Event'])` or `df['Event']=df['Event'].replace(event_types)`

Comment: df['Event']=df['Event'].replace(event_types) was it. Make it an answer!!